# Determining proper word for a situation

Tags: word-usage

I work at a call center.  I said something somebody I work didn't like.  I was working.  They came behind me while working and just kept calling my name and would not leave me alone.  I reported this to HR as harassment.  HR told me this was not harassment.  So, what is the proper word to describe a situation like this?

Comment: Cascabel is right.  It may be that ‘harassment’ is covered by the company’s code of conduct, in which case you need to study it and decide if HR is taking a fair view of the situation.  At all events the issue you raise sounds more to me like a legal or quasi-legal one than a matter of English language usage.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that **harassment** *is* the correct word.

Here are two of the senses of the Merriam-Webster definition of [**harass**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/harassment):

> **1 b (1)** : to annoy persistently
>   // was *harassing* his younger brother
>   **1 b (2)** : to create an unpleasant or hostile situation for
>   especially by uninvited and unwelcome verbal or physical conduct
>   // was being *harassed* by her classmates
>   // claims that the police were unfairly *harassing* him

From the description of a colleague standing behind you and constantly repeating your name, despite you saying you didn't like—and, presumably, being *annoying* in a *persistent* fashion, I would say it was a clear case of *harassment* based on the English definition of the word.

---

Having said that, however, the HR department at your company might have a different definition of the word they use as part of their own policies.

If so, a more accurate response could have been:

> "We acknowledge that it was harassment in the commonly used sense of the word, but it's unfortunately not something we can act on. Per our policies, actionable harassment is defined as  . . ."

Comment: +1  agree with you

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate all responses.  This give me very good insight into the matter.

Answer (score 0):

I would call the behavior of your colleagues *DISTURBANCE*.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary 
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disturbance:

***disturbance***

: the act of disturbing

: the state of being disturbed

// apologized for creating a disturbance